# How to pass an unrelated class in a constructor of another class?

Tags: c++

Extra line of code can be added only to the place where '>>' sign is present.
My targeted input and output is as follows:

**Input:**  15

**Output :** 16:15:17:16:

I need help only in

```
cout << r.get() << ":";
```

part. An explanation would be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

        class A {
            int i;
            public:
                A(int ai) : i(ai) {}
                int get() const { return i; }
                void update() { ++i; }
        };

        class B { 
            int i;
            public:
                B(int ai) : i(ai) {}
                int get() const { return i; }
    //>>
    operator A() {return A(i);}
    void update() { ++i; }
    }; // End of class B

    int main() {
        int i;
        cin >> i;

        A a(i++);
        B b(i);

        const B &r = static_cast<B>(a);
        a.update();
        cout << a.get() << ":";
        cout << r.get() << ":";

        const A &s = static_cast<A>(b);
        b.update();
        cout << b.get() << ":";
        cout << s.get() << ":";

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: My psychic powers tell me you are seeking assistance. Unfortunately things get fuzzy after that. Frankly I'm not that good a psychic. But I do know a bit about programming. You should focus your efforts on sorting out `const B &r = static_cast<B>(a);` There is no relationship between `A` and `B` so you cannot safely turn an `A` into a `B` by any means. Expand on what you are attempting to do and someone can likely help you out with a more concrete answer.

Comment: Yes, I am seeking assistance. I cannot change that line `const B &r = static_cast<B>(a);` , that's a constraint. And again, yes, if it is for learning, I don't find any wrong in seeking assistance.  @user4581301

Comment: Can you change class `A` and class `B` to establish a relationship or add a function that can convert from one to the other?

Comment: And no, there is nothing wrong with asking for help, but you need to be clear on what you are asking and the parameters of the problem. If we do not know the rules, we cannot suggest solutions that are within the rules.

Comment: I can only add code to the line with `>>` sign. Nothing else can be changed or modified.

Comment: I think I can create a constructor like `B(const A&){ }` in class B by which I can take a class A object as an argument of constructor of class B, but what to do after that ?

Comment: I think that makes your question "How to I change `operator A() {return A(i);}` to allow me to make a `B` from an `A`?"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180895/discussion-between-satyaki-majumder-and-user4581301).

Comment: sounds like a class assignment. Also sounds like the professor is trying to make you find fancy tricks that never get used in real life. Hard to say tho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot solve the asker's problem by modifying a conversion operator in class `B`. `B`'s conversion operators only tell the constructor how to make another datatype out of a `B`. To do this with a conversion operator, the operator needs to be in class `A`.

```
class B; // forward declaration of B so that A knows it exists

class A
{
    int i;
public:
    A(int ai) :
            i(ai)
    {
    }
    int get() const
    {
        return i;
    }
    void update()
    {
        ++i;
    }
    operator B(); // cannot implement the function yet because we do not have a 
                  // complete definition of B. Without a definition of B we cannot 
                  // construct B excluding forward defined helper functions that are 
                  // implemented later, gaining us nothing.
};
```

Then later after `B` is fully defined,

```
A::operator B()
{
    return B(i); // now we have enough information to construct a B
}
```

Note: We can reduce some of this messiness by moving the definition of `B` to before the definition of `A`. Unfortunately this makes the code required to support the

```
const A &s = static_cast<A>(b);
```

that comes later in the code require forward declaration of `A` and the implementation of the `B` to `A` conversion operator outside the definition of `B`.

An alternative is adding a constructor to `B` that takes an `A`

```
B::B(const A& a): i(a.get())
{

}
```

and vice-versa for `A`.